# The getter 'data' isn't defined for the type 'QuerySnapshot<Object?>'

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch data from firestore database. But my code gives me error while doing it. Can someone help? Here is the code,

```
getImage() {
    Map<String, dynamic> img = {};
    CollectionReference collectionReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('user');
    collectionReference.snapshots().listen((snapshot) {
      img = snapshot.data.docs[0].data();
     });
    return img['imageUrl'];

  }
```

It shows error in the term 'data' which is in bold. "img = snapshot.**data**.docs[0].data();"
[image]

Comment: Can you add error stacktrace?

Comment: Do you have any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace this line:

```
 img = snapshot.data.docs[0].data();
```

With:

```
 img = snapshot.docs[0].get('imageUrl);
 });
return img;
}
```

You don't have to use `.data` because you are not in a stream builder or future builder. This is the direct object from firebase's listen method.

Comment: still not working.

Comment: Error: The getter 'data' isn't defined for the class 'QuerySnapshot<Object?>'.
 - 'QuerySnapshot' is from 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-3.1.17/lib/cloud_firestore.dart').
 - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'data'.
      img = snapshot.data.docs[0].get('imageUrl');

Comment: There is no presence of `data` in my response.

Comment: it is showing error in getter 'data' in 'snapshot.data'. I have now added an image of the error in the bottom of the question.

Comment: oooooh, remove data. Just use `snapshot.docs` and you should be good. I edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I tried but it gives null value

Comment: I tried but it gives null value

Comment: That is a different error, and has something to do with your collection, the solution solves the error you are facing.